# Good server-side open source frameworks to write monitoring dashboards on the MS stack

Tags: monitoring

Folks - I'm looking to implement a simple web dashboard to plug-in a set of PowerShell scripts that monitor my infrastructure (did backups occurred?, are all machines healthy?, etc. etc.)

I'm trying to avoid writing the harness: the website and UI (status indicators, etc.), triggering the scripts, standard interface for scripts to report-back the status of an indicator (i.e. green/yellow/red, error text, etc.).

Basically I want to focus on writing my monitoring scripts.  The output of those scripts would conform to a simple interface and as such they are easy to plug-in to the dashboard framework.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios Core is a fantastic front-end for custom monitoring scripts. I have used it (running natively on Linux) to monitor dozens of Windows systems and services. The configuration options are limitless -- including, for example, changing the default check interval from minutes to seconds in order to support real-time alerting.

You would need an extremely lightweight agent called NSClient++ (or similar) installed wherever you're running the Powershell scripts, and the agent is of course configured to accept connections only from the monitoring server.

If you have no Linux at all in your environment, there is also a [Windows/Cygwin port](https://www.itefix.net/nagwin), which I have not used.

Comment: thanks for the rec!  Looking forward to digging deeper into Nagios.